# Hardhat - how to Verify a Contract

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, hardhat

I've successfully deployed an `ERC721` contract to `GOERLI` using `Hardhat` - and the contract is working **perfectly**, but when I try to ***verify*** the contract, I keep getting errors.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the arguments being passed during the contract's deployment.

Here's the deployment code:

```
  constructor() ERC721("FunNFTs!", "Funs") {   
      // code goes here...
   }
```

Sine the contract works, I tried to verify it, and ran this from Terminal:

```
npx hardhat verify --network goerli 0x0123...789 "FunNFTs!" "Funs"
```

But that gives me the following:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/johnsmith/Desktop/MyFunNFTProject/artifacts/build-info/faab804f0b89fb637a395cffcbbb44b8.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/johnsmith/Desktop/MyFunNFTProject/artifacts/build-info/faab804f0b89fb637a395cffcbbb44b8.json'
}
```

I should note that I have no idea why its asking me for this file: `"faab804f0b89fb637a395cffcbbb44b8.json"`

Cause that file doesn't seems to exist anywhere on my computer.

Otherwise, I tried separating those 2 arguments with a comma, like so:

"FunNFTs!", "Funs"

as well as putting them in " ( ) " or "[ ]" - but I get the same error every time.

So I'm pretty much stuck.

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan` plugin installed. Then you may have to:

1. Delete `artifacts` and `cache` folders
2. Run `npx hardhat compile`
3. Verify again

Answer (score 2):

There is a different way when you have more than one argument.
[image]

You can find that here https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/tree/main/packages/hardhat-etherscan#complex-arguments

Comment: You're totally right - and I completely forgot (literally have it in my notes!) about needing that `arguments.js` file because of the multiple `constructor` arguments.  *HOWEVER*, when I included it in my `verify` statement, the compiler then pointed out - correctly - that my `constructor` actually does NOT have any arguments in it. And that's true. It does not. It instantiates an `ERC721` contract, which DOES have arguments, but the "main" `constructor` does *not.* So the solution was simply clearing out the `cache` and `artifacts` folders and deploying everything anew...‍♂️